# Laravel 5.6: Many-to-many relationship returns empty object

Tags: php, database, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.6

I'm setting up a many-to-many relationship in Laravel 5.6 models but, since I'm not following Laravel's naming convention, I'm surely making a mistake on table/foreign keys name that makes it not working.

My tables related to the blog section all have a `blog_` prefix:

1. `blog_posts` collects all posts info (`id`, `title`, `article`, etc.)
2. `blog_tags` defines the tags that can be used to tag the post (`id`, `name`)
3. `blog_posts_tags` is the pivot table that creates the relationships between posts and tags (`id`, `post_id`, `tag_id`)

As said, I'm trying to set up the relationships in Laravel:

Model: **BlogPost.php**

```
/**
 * The tags that belong to the post.
 */
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\BlogTag', 'blog_posts_tags', 'post_id', 'tag_id'); 
}
```

Model: **BlogTag.php**

```
/**
 * The posts that belong to the tag.
 */
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\BlogPost', 'blog_posts_tags', 'tag_id', 'post_id');
}
```

The problem is that, when I call `tags()` method, the returned object hasn't the tags inside:

```
$post = BlogPost::find($id);
$tags = $post->tags();
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$post->tags()` returns you releated instance with query builder.

if you want to get releated tag values, just use name of relation

example: `$tags = $post->tags;`

```
foreach($tags as $tag){
   var_dump($tag);
}
```